# Unit testing angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have an angular module called 'widgets'. Here is it's signature being used in my app:

```
var app = angular.module('widgets', [
    'widget.Panel',
    'widget.List',
    'services'
]);
```

I also have a controller being created off of `app`:

```
app.controller('clientListController', ['$scope', '$http', 'ServiceProvider', function ($scope, $http, ServiceProvider) {
```

I'm trying to write a unit test for 'clientListController'. Here is what I've done:

```
describe('clientListController', function () {
    var ctrl, scope;

    beforeEach(angular.module('widgets'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('clientListController', { $scope: scope });
    }));

    it("should define openClient function", function () {
        expect(scope.openClient).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

When I try to run the tests, I get an error:

```
Error: Argument 'clientListController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Is there something wrong with how I've written the test? How come `clientListController` isn't defined? Does it have something to do with the dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `beforeEach(module('widgets'))` or `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('widgets'))`.  You need to set a module for angular-mocks to work from.  `angular.mock.module` gets assigned to `window.module` for convenience.  Your code is just getting the module from angular and not setting it for angular-mocks to use.